# catkin_pkg is missing topological_order

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- Ubuntu 12.04
- ROS Groovy

After installing `python-catkin-pkg` and `ros-groovy-catkin` from the ROS debian repositories, and manually creating a catkin workspace and then calling `cmake ../src` from the build directory, I saw the following error:

```
/opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/em/order_packages.cmake.em:6: error: <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named topological_order
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 3288, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 3286, in main
    invoke(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 3269, in invoke
    interpreter.wrap(interpreter.file, (file, name))
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2273, in wrap
    self.fail(e)
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2264, in wrap
    apply(callable, args)
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2337, in file
    self.safe(scanner, done, locals)
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2379, in safe
    self.parse(scanner, locals)
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2399, in parse
    token.run(self, locals)
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 1410, in run
    interpreter.execute(self.code, locals)
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2576, in execute
    exec statements in self.globals
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named topological_order
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  
  execute_process(/home/jbohren/versioned/ros/maintain_catkin/ws/build/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh
  /usr/bin/empy --raw-errors -F
  /home/jbohren/versioned/ros/maintain_catkin/ws/build/catkin_generated/order_packages.py
  -o
  /home/jbohren/versioned/ros/maintain_catkin/ws/build/catkin_generated/order_packages.cmake
  /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/em/order_packages.cmake.em) returned
  error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/em_expand.cmake:17 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:34 (em_expand)
  CMakeLists.txt:45 (catkin_workspace)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46888/catkin_pkg-is-missing-topological_order/) by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5809 on 2012-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was happening because `python-catkin-pkg` was out of sync in the debian repositories (version 0.1.0) and `ros-groovy-catkin` now requires at least version 0.1.3.

You can download the latest `python-catkin-pkg` from ros-shadow-fixed [here](http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu/pool/main/c/catkinpkg/).

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1